# hive column check for string 'null' and real NULL

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a query, where many columns need to check for 'null' or NULL then move space

right now we have `column1='null' then ' ' else .... end`

there are many columns with above condition

I want to do a replace all in hql query where i can make `column1='null' or column1 is NULL`

as there are many columns, i cant do at once, is there are way i can replace just ='null' to achieve both 'null' and NULL

```
column1 in ('null',NULL) then ' ' did not work
column1='null' or NULL then ' ' did not work
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nvl function.  It will replace the null with the values you want.

```
nvl(column1," ")
```

If you want to compare with null then you should use ‘is null or is not nullin or = ` doesn’t work